# Configuring Debian Buster (10) for IPv6 with DHCP

Tags: debian, ipv6

I had a Debian Jessie server instance hosted by a provider. This instance had its IPv6 an IPv4 address defined statically. I upgraded my server to Debian Buster, and its IPv4 address is defined by DHCP. But the IPv6 address is not automatically set.

This is what I get with ifconfig:

```
eno1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 151.80.**.**  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 151.80.**.**
        inet6 fe80::eea8:6bff:****:****  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether ec:a8:6b:f1:**:**  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 925  bytes 78623 (76.7 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 380  bytes 55091 (53.7 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 20  memory 0xf7c00000-f7c20000
```

The IPv6 address of my server is 2001:41d0:e:****:****:****. This is what I defined in my DNS as AAAA address. It was working perfectly with Jessie and a static configuration.

Why is the IPv6 address not set automatically by DHCP ? Is it because they don’t provide it with DHCP information ? Or is it because Debian ignores it and doesn’t set it ?

I can’t configure the IPv6 address because I’m lacking the gateway address.

Comment: Does your server forward IPv6 traffic? IPv6 address autoconfiguration does not happen by default if forwarding is enabled, see http://strugglers.net/~andy/blog/2011/09/04/linux-ipv6-router-advertisements-and-forwarding/ for example. However, default route assignment should work regardless. (Even with hand-configured static IPv6 addresses.)

Comment: The server is not forwarding IPv6 traffic. The problem was solved by defining the IPv6 address and routes statically.  I gave an answer with the solution, but apparently the answer was not published.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem.

I tried to apply the procedure provided by my hosting provider here: https://docs.ovh.com/fr/dedicated/network-ipv6/.
Unfortunately it didn’t work.

The reason is that the network is named eno1 and not eth0 when I execute `ifconfig`.

Here is what I did.

In /etc/sysctl.conf I added the following at the end of the file:

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.autoconf = 0
net.ipv6.conf.default.autoconf = 0
net.ipv6.conf.eno1.autoconf = 0
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra = 0
net.ipv6.conf.default.accept_ra = 0
net.ipv6.conf.eno1.accept_ra = 0
```

In /etc/network/interfaces I added the following just after `iface eth0 inet dhcp`.

```
iface eno1 inet6 static
    address 2001:41d0:****:****:****:****
    netmask 128
    post-up /sbin/ip -family inet6 route add 2001:41d0:****:**ff:ff:ff:ff:ff dev eno1
    post-up /sbin/ip -family inet6 route add default via 2001:41d0:****:**ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    pre-down /sbin/ip -family inet6 route del default via 2001:41d0:****:**ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    pre-down /sbin/ip -family inet6 route del 2001:41d0:****:**ff:ff:ff:ff:ff dev eno1
```

I then restart the network with the command `/etc/init.d/networking restart`.

I then see the static IPv6 address shown in the output of `ifconfig` as expected.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same problem. Your post helped me, thanks.
here is my procedure.

**verification**

```
ifconfig  
nano /etc/sysctl.conf  
nano /etc/network/interfaces  
nano /etc/network/interfaces.d/50-cloud-init  
/etc/init.d/networking restart
```

ok,

**ipv6 config**
create (see in /50-cloud-init)

```
nano /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg
```

add

> network: {config: disabled}

```
nano /etc/sysctl.conf
```

add

> net.ipv6.conf.all.autoconf = 0 #(doc ovh)
> net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra = 0 #(doc ovh)
> net.ipv4.ip_forward = 0 #(webmin panel)
> net.ipv6.conf.default.autoconf = 0 #(your post)
> net.ipv6.conf.eno1.autoconf = 0 #(your post)
> net.ipv6.conf.default.accept_ra = 0 #(your post)
> net.ipv6.conf.eno1.accept_ra = 0 #(your post)

```
sh sysctl -p #(doc ovh)
```

result

> /usr/sbin/sysctl: /usr/sbin/sysctl: cannot execute binary file

(so i choose reboot)

```
systemctl reboot
```

ok

**registration of ipv6 and routing**

```
ip addr add IPV6/64 dev IF  
ip -6 route add IPV6_GATEWAY dev IF  
ip -6 route add default via IPV6_GATEWAY dev IF
```

```
nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

## IPV6

> iface IF inet6 static
> address YOUR_IPv6
> netmask 64 # (or 128)
>
> post-up /sbin/ip -f inet6 route add IPv6_GATEWAY dev IF
> post-up /sbin/ip -f inet6 route add default via IPv6_GATEWAY
> pre-down /sbin/ip -f inet6 route del IPv6_GATEWAY dev IF
> pre-down /sbin/ip -f inet6 route del default via Ipv6_GATEWAY

```
/etc/init.d/networking restart
```

ok

(test ping)

```
date && ping -c 6 proof.ovh.net  
ping6 -c 4 2001:4860:4860::8888 (doc ovh)  
date && mtr -rbwz -c 10 -6 [ipv6 of my connection]
```

all ok

since my connection

```
date && ping6 -c 6 [server's ipv6]  
date && mtr -rbwz -c 10 -6 [server's ipv6]
```

ok

```
systemctl reboot
```

ok

```
ifconfig
```

ok

```
ip addr
```

ok
tests ping ok

☺️

Thanks for your post

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please take some time to check the [editing help](https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help). In particular, ensure that verbatim reproduction of commands and file content examples use block code formatting ( \`\`\` (newline) code (newline) \`\`\` ) and make use of lists.

Comment: Thank you. I progress.

Comment: Many thanks to you chatchai j